# Calculating idle time of resources using simpy?

Tags: python, simpy

i am trying to simulate an `M/M/c` Queue using `SimPy` 3 On `Python 3.6` it was easy to calculate various performance measures such as `service time`, `waiting time...` but i can't seem to find a way to calculate `idle time` of resources, i've looked in the documentations for `SimPy` but no luck, please help i've been on this for days

i have a feeling i have to extend the `Resource` class but i just don't know enough `Python` to get this done

```
arrival = prng.PRNG(50000)

service = prng.PRNG(10000)

simulation_time =  30.0

service_time = 10.0

arrival_time = 2.5

data = [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]

data[3].append(0)

def source(env, counter):
    i = 0
    while True:
        i += 1
        t = arrival.nextExponential(1.0 / arrival_time)
        c = customer(env, i, t, counter, service_time)
        env.process(c)
        yield env.timeout(t)

def customer(env, i, t, counter, service_time):

    arrive = env.now

    data[6].append(len(counter.queue))

    with counter.request() as req:

        data[0].append(i)

        data[1].append(t)

        data[2].append(arrive)

        if (len(data[2])) >= 2:
            n = len(data[2]) - 1
            p = n - 1
            data[3].append(data[2][n] - data[2][p])

        results = yield req

        wait = env.now - arrive

        data[5].append(wait)

        tib = service.nextExponential(1.0 / service_time)

        data[4].append(round(tib, 2))

        data[7].append(wait + tib)

        yield env.timeout(tib)

env = simpy.Environment()

counter = simpy.Resource(env, capacity=5)

env.process(source(env, counter))

env.run(until=simulation_time)

total_wait_time = 0.0

total_time_in_system = 0.0

total_service_time = 0.0

total_interarrival_time = 0.0

print("No.\tArrival Time\tClock Time\tInterarrival Time\tService Time\tWait Time\tQueue Length\tTotal Time In System")

def display(i):
    print()
    print("Average Waiting Time => %.2f Minutes" % (total_wait_time / i))
    print("Average Service Time => %.2f Minutes" % (total_service_time / i))
    print("Average Time Spent In System => %.2f Minutes" % (total_time_in_system / i))
    print("Average Interarrival Time => %.2f Minutes" % (total_interarrival_time / i))

for i in range(0, len(data[0])):
    try:
        id = data[0][i]
        arrivalTime = data[1][i]
        clockTime = data[2][i]
        interarrivalTime = data[3][i]
        serviceTime = data[4][i]
        waitTime = data[5][i]
        queueLength = data[6][i]
        totalTimeInSystem = data[7][i]

        total_wait_time += waitTime

        total_time_in_system += totalTimeInSystem

        total_service_time += serviceTime

        total_interarrival_time += interarrivalTime

        print("%d\t%.2f\t\t%.2f\t\t%.2f\t\t\t%.2f\t\t%.2f\t\t%0d\t\t%.2f" % (id, arrivalTime, clockTime, interarrivalTime, serviceTime, waitTime, queueLength, totalTimeInSystem))
    except IndexError as identifier:
        display(i + 1)
        exit()

display(i + 1)
```

**so what i need is the total `idle time` of resources?**

**thank you**

Comment: Shouln’t it be easy to calculate the idle time when you know the simulation time and the times when the resource was used? E.g., if `env.now == 10` and the resources has been used from 2–4 from 5–6, the resource was idle for 7 time units.

Comment: i couldn't find any data on resource usage...@StefanScherfke

Comment: You can collect that data relatively easy using the monitoring techniques described in the docs.